# Loose fitting door lock in security strike pocket

Tags: doors

It's actually for an office door with a self closing mechanism and an electronic security strike. The lock fits loosely in the security strike when latched. I had put felt pads on the door frame to dampen the sound as it was quite loud before (wooden door hitting a metal frame). The pads worked, but the door still bounces in the security strike when latched closed (loose fitting). The door is mainly glass with a wooden frame mounted by four hinges and set into a steel frame.

How can this be adjusted to alleviate the bouncing effect when the door latches closed?

Comment: Have you tried to soften the self closer?

Comment: Yes with several little adjustments and almost to the point of it not latching at all, but the door still bounces.

Comment: Have you tried to stiffen the self-closer? Firm and slow might be the ticket.

Answer (score 1):

If you added felt to the door stop (frame), add thicker ones to make up the extra slop you experience.

Other than relocating the latch on the door itself, which is not for a novice, extra bumper thickness is the simplest way to go.

Comment: Or door silencers... https://homebydecor.com/?page=products&action=view&manufacturerID=87&productID=1608&linkID=17972&sku=1608&gclid=CjwKCAjwkdL6BRAREiwA-kiczI9ef6RL_f6KKt6SxTctiy4L_Gi-IA1SWhME8I6-ySx6IaHYMRZf-xoC1tsQAvD_BwE